# GraphicsMagick on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, graphicsmagick

I am using Google cloud's app engine to deploy a small node js application. One of the requirements of the app is GraphicsMagick.

Is there a way to install this package onto app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by building and using a custom runtime. From [Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#dependencies):

> To enable the use of Node.js packages that require native extensions,
>   the following Debian packages are pre-installed in the [Docker
>   image](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker).
>
> - [build-essential](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git)
> - [ca-certificates](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git)
> - [curl](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git)
> - [python](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git)
> - [libkrb5-dev](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git)
> - [imagemagick](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git)
> - [git](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/git)
>
> If your application requires additional operating-system-level
>   dependencies, you will need to use a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes) based on this
>   runtime to install the appropriate packages.

And from [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build):

> To create a custom runtime you need:
>
> - An `app.yaml` file that describes your application's runtime configuration.
> - A `Dockerfile` that configures the runtime environment. In many cases, this can be just one line specifying a base image.
> - To ensure your application is listening on port 8080 and has request handlers that respond to lifecycle events, such as start, stop, and
>     health check requests.
>
> **Note:** Google supplies [base images](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#configuring_the_dockerfile) that you can customize, but you aren't required to use these. You can use other images so long as
>   they satisfy the conditions in the bulleted list above.

You should go through the entire page, though, lots of useful info in there, the above is just a short summary quote.